# I am getting ERROR - Is my sql query executing? - Here I am trying to get QS_SIZE -- What do think I am doing wrong?

Tags: java, sql

```
private void populateSizeById(String Id) {
    String method = ".populateSizeById() "; //Is this method incorrect?
    enter code here

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    String Size = ""; //Assigning Size
    try {
          preparedStatement = super.prepareStatement(GET_SIZE_BY_ID,                   ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY); 
//assign sql -- thinking sql query is not executing.. 
        super.setString(1, Id, preparedStatement); // ????????
        ResultSet resultSet = super.executeQuery(preparedStatement); // ID
        while (ResultSetHelper.next(resultSet)) {

            Size = ResultSetHelper.getString(resultSet, "FS_SIZE"); //FS_SIZE
            if (null != Size && !"".equals(Size)) super.setFieldValue("QS_SIZE",     Size); // QS_SIZE ERROR here.. Doesnt get the value here.. Size is turning into null               
        }
    } catch(MaximumResultsExceededException mreEx) {
        throw new CivSQLException(TRACE_TAG + method, mreEx);
    } finally {
        super.cleanup(preparedStatement);
    }

    } //What wrong am I doing..

     private final static String GET_SIZE_BY_ID = " SELECT F.FS_SIZE  " + " FROM       TABLE F  " + "   WHERE F.ID = ? "; // SQL query to run
```

I am trying to get the size value to QS_SIZE by executing a SQL  query. What do you think am I doing wrong? Please help, I am still a learner and trying to understand ....